# Accessing File/Directory Outside of Webroot - PHP

Tags: php

I have seen numerous posts on this but most are older and examples are unclear for my use. I have a couple of examples where I would like to access files outside of my webroot.

The first is for sensitive scripts such as database connection files. If our webroot is `/www` lets say this file is located two directories above our webroot (`../../www`).

The second would be stored content such as images or documents. If our webroot is `/www` lets say a needed file is located in  `SERVER_ROOT/content/documents/file.txt`.

My current means of accessing a directory containing something needed outside of webroot is by doing something similar to the following:

`$dir = __DIR__.'../../../../restricted_dir`

What is the secure and correct way to access directories and files outside of our webroot?

Comment: There is nothing insecure about what you're doing inherently, as long as you don't append user input directly to the path without making sure it's a valid path. I'm not sure why what you're already doing should be an issue?

Comment: @MatsLindh I suppose my question is more surrounding best practices when it comes to including these files in other scripts or accessing their content. If what I am already doing is standard, then all is well.

Comment: If you're talking about actual code and libraries, you probably want to go with something that [integrates with an PSR-4 compatible autoloader](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and works together with the composer autoloader if necessary. You can use `realpath` in your configuration file to define paths, and use `__DIR__` (as you're doing) to set up a path that's relative to your configuration file.